# WAMP install issues, 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

I've installed **WAMP** successfully and it works as expected until I've tried to use it with a **Dropbox** folder, having followed a tutorial.

Owing to that challenge, I've uninstalled, deleted all the files, and have re-installed WAMP after a system restore.

I can access **`localhost`**, but not **`localhost/phpmyadmin`**; I keep getting a *Forbidden error (403)* with the following message: ***`you do not have permission to view this directory`***.

I literally spent all afternoon yesterday and all morning reading every single Google result I could for solutions and I still can't fix it.

I've already tried common solutions such as modifying the *configuration files* to no avail.

Below is the content of my Apache error log:

```
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:39 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:39 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:39 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4992
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:40 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Child process is running
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:40 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:40 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:40 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:40 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:50 2012] [notice] Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:50 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:51 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Released the start mutex
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:52 2012] [notice] Child 4992: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:52 2012] [notice] Child 4992: Child process is exiting
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:52 2012] [notice] Parent: Child process exited successfully.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep 10 2011 11:34:11
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4576
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 4576: Child process is running
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 4576: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 4576: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 4576: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jan 24 15:53:53 2012] [notice] Child 4576: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Jan 24 15:54:01 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/WAMP/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/, referer: http://localhost/
```

There was no PHP log.

Following, is the content of the MySQL error log:

```
120124 15:53:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120124 15:53:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120124 15:53:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120124 15:53:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120124 15:53:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120124 15:53:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file .\ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
120124 15:53:38  InnoDB: Setting file .\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
120124 15:53:39  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
120124 15:53:39  InnoDB: Log file .\ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file .\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
120124 15:53:41  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120124 15:53:42 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 0
120124 15:53:43 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120124 15:53:43 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.16-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Check .htaccess and you httpd.conf files for allow/deny rules relating to the phpmyadmin directory

Comment: I had modified the allow,deny rules but that didn't work, although it seemed to be a common fix for others.

Comment: can you post your error_log entry?

Comment: I've added it to my original post

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! Did you add index.php to the DocumentIndex directive in the httpd.conf and restart? I'm guessing that index.php isn't there, and so apache doesn't have a default page to load.  Let me know.

Comment: No, thank you for taking a look! index.php is already there in the DocumentIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your server is configured to block your IPv6 loopback address:

`[Tue Jan 24 15:54:01 2012] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: C:/WAMP/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/, referer: http://localhost/`

Try allowing it or if that fails try disabling IPv6 on your network interface.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I'm afraid it all goes over my head :-/  I've Google'd "disabling IPv6" and have un-ticked the IPv6 box in my Local Area Connections Properties panel.  That hasn't fixed anything thus far.

Comment: What's the content of your C:\WAMP\alias\phpmyadmin.conf file?

Comment: @JamesStanzaMiddleditch That's the problem right there. Only 127.0.0.1 is allowed to connect. Try adding `Allow from ::1` below the line `Allow from 127.0.0.1` and things should start working.

Comment: I don't what any of this means, but it worked! It's been doing my head in for days. THANK YOU